# Retrieving a record for the last date received and returning the value of another column in that row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I have the following query which is returning me total number of expected records :

```
select a.New_FirstName + ' ' + a.New_LastName as 'Account Name', a.New_MPRNNumber,MAX(b.New_readdate) as 'Last SC Read Date'     
from AccountExtensionBase as a
left join New_meterreadingextensionBase as b on a.AccountId = b.new_account_meterreadingid
where New_AccountType in (5,7)
and b.New_ReadTypeCodeMM = 'SC'
and b.New_ReadReasonCodeMM = 95
group by a.New_FirstName,a.New_LastName, a.New_MPRNNumber
order by a.New_MPRNNumber
```

However when I add the New_ReadingValue property to the select list as follows I am returning an incorrect number of rows:

```
select a.New_FirstName + ' ' + a.New_LastName as 'Account Name', a.New_MPRNNumber,MAX(b.New_readdate) as 'Last SC Read Date', New_ReadingValue
```

I understand why this is happening in that the two readings are different but I only want to get 1 reading for the latest read date, what is the best approach for doing this? can i set up distinct on two or three of the other properties?

If I try the above then It complains that New_ReadngValue is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Other than that, your question seems a classic example of the [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server) problem.

Comment: Thanks for the greatest-n-per-group link not sure how this works in my situation as it is a bit beyond my current skillset but I will try thanks